# Search box not rendering the same on FIrefox as how it is on Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am having difficulty in fixing an issue with rendering a search box the way it is working on chrome on all other browser. Fire fox is totally showing the search box differently. Provided below some screenshots:

Chrome:
 https://gyazo.com/8014660292a4e23390bb5dec1100bda0

Firefox :
 https://gyazo.com/7fb0c75410f428404be7e64d495e23e3

HTML:

```
<div id="headerSearchBox">
    {* Header Search Box Area *}
    {if $config.settings.search}

            <div class="container">
                <form action="{linkto page="search.php"}" method="get" id="searchFormTest">
                    <input type="hidden" name="clearSearch" value="true">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div id="custom-search-input">
                            <div style="background-color: black" class="search_bttn input-group col-md-12">
                            <input type="text" id="searchPhrase" name="searchPhrase" class="searchInputBox" value="{$lang.enterKeywords}" placeholder="Suchbegriff oder Bildnummer">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button id="clickableAwesomeFont" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="submit">
                                <i style="font-size: 20px; color: white;" class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                    </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
    {/if}
</div>
```

Please can you advice me on how to go about fixing it ??

Thank You

Comment: Where is your CSS?